# how to show long poll result with php echo

Tags: javascript, jquery

My am working with a long poll script which working well if I append any text to test. Now I want to show long polling result of user.php collect from data update.php. I used my polling script at user.php page.

Here, If I used "test polling" as below, Its work well

```
    $("#updatepost").append("test polling");
```

But I want append here my update.php file's echo

my full code
In my user.php

```
<script>
function addmsg(type, msg){
    $("#updatepost").append("test polling");
}

function waitForMsg(){
    /* This requests the url "msgsrv.php"
    When it complete (or errors)*/
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "update.php",

        async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
        cache: false,
        timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

        success: function(data){ /* called when request to barge.php completes */
            addmsg(".upbox1", data); /* Add response to a .msg div (with the "new" class)*/
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, /* Try again after.. */
                15000); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="updatepost">
</div>
```

In my update.php

```
    $u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM updateside WHERE `parent_id`='".$parent."' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY created DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($u)) {
$parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
$to_id = $row['to_id'];
$sub = $row['sub'];
$detail = $row['detail'];
$time = $row['created'];

// I want to show this result at my polling
echo '<div class="upbox1" id="'.$parent_id.'"><div class="upbox2">'.$from_id.' '.$sub.' '.$to_pname.'</div>
<div class="upbox3">';
if ($detail=="") {echo '';}
else echo''.$detail.;
echo'</div></a><div class="upbox4">'.$time.'</div>
</div>';
}
```

Comment: what is the `".upbox1"` parameter you pass to `addmsg` function ? What are the two arguments of that function supposed to mean ?

Comment: Sorry, I just trying this. .

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `addmsg` function to

```
function addmsg(type, msg){
    $("#updatepost").append(msg);
}
```

it will append the results of your ajax call inside the `#updatepost` element.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qyjgxh7n/ (*demo url for ajax call and results*). So check if your ajax returns what you expect..

Comment: Thank u sir, but cannot work in my page. If I show php result, I added in my update.php page: $result['id'] = $row['id'];
$result['detail'] = $row['detail']; header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
exit; How to show it by JS? I am trying this: $("#updatepost").html('<div class="result" id="' + id + '"> " ' + data.detail + ' "</div>');